# Install Fonts with Inno Setup - Replacing fonts that are locked

Tags: fonts, inno-setup, font-awesome

I'm using Inno Setup to install the Fontawesome font for a desktop application on Windows. First install usually works fine as the fonts aren't installed, but on subsequent installs I frequently run into locking problems:

[image: Inno Installer locked font file Dialog]

In order to install the font I'm using:

```
Source: "FontAwesome.ttf"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "FontAwesome";\
        Flags: uninsneveruninstall
```

Now I know I can use `Flags: onlyifdoesntexist` to install the fonts only if they don't exist and that does work. However, on occasion I need to update the Font due to a version change and new fonts that have been added.

The error apparently occurs only if something is using the font. Besides the main installed application, I'm using Chrome and have pages open that use FontAwesome and apparently that's also locking the installed font.

Ideally what I need to have happen is if the font is locked have it replaced after the next reboot or after the font becomes unblocked.

It also looks like Inno is trying to replace the font each and every time even though the the font version is the same. According to [the docs](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection) (bottom of the document) files are only supposed to be replaced if the install version is higher, but that doesn't appear to be happening with the font wanting to install each time.

Is there any way to make Inno properly deal with Font Updates if the font in question is in use?

Comment: Your edit about font version: That's a new question. It's not related to the locking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add the `*.ttf` to the [`CloseApplicationsFilter`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_closeapplicationsfilter).

```
CloseApplicationsFilter=*.exe,*.dll,*.chm,*.ttf
```

It should make Inno Setup check, if the font is locked, and offer an user to close Chrome (or other application) to allow the replacement.